# How could we prove the correctness of the algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science

Consider two sets $D=\{ d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n\}$ and $E=\{ e_1, e_2, \dots, e_m \}$ and consider an other variable $K \geq 0$. 
Show that we can answer in time $O((n+m) \lg (n+m))$ the following question:
Is there is a pair of numbers $a,b$ where $a \in D, b \in E$ such that $|a-b| \leq K$?

The algorithm should answer the  above question with YES or NO.
Describe the algorithm, show its correctness and show that its time complexity is $O((n+m) \lg (n+m))$.

I wrote the following algorithm:

```
int binary_search(int A[], int key, int low, int high, int K) 
{ 
   if (high < low) return 0; 
   else{ 
       int mid=low+floor((high-low)/2); 
       if (A[mid]<key-K) return binary_search(A, key, mid+1, high); 
       else if (A[mid]>k+key) return binary_search(A, key, low, mid-1 ); 
       else return mid; 
   } 
} 



Algorithm(D,E,K) {
  HeapSort(E); 
  low=1; 
  high=m; 
  i=1; 
  p=0 
  while (i<=n and p==0){ 
         p=binary_search(E, D[i], low, high, K ); 
         i++; 
  } 
  if (p==0) printf("NO \n"); 
  else printf("YES \n"); 
}
```

We can prove the correctness of binary_search as follows, right?

Base case:

We suppose that we have an array of size 1.

Then it holds $low=high=mid$.

If the if-statement holds then we call the function binary_search(A, key, low+1, low) and since $high<low$, the function will return $0$. The result is right, because we have only one element that does not satisfy the desired property , we are looking further for an other elemenent,but since there is no other one, it means that the desired element doesn't exist.

Similarly for the case when the else-if-statament holds.

Furthermore, no matter which sie the array has, if the element we are looking at has the desired property, then the else-statement holds,so the algorithm returns the right position.

Induction hypothesis:

We suppose that binary_search gives the right result for arrays with size $<n$.

Induction step:

Now we consider an array of size $n$.
If the if- or else-if statement holds, we call the binary_search for an array of size $<n$, so from the induction hypothesis we know that we will have the right result.

Otherwise, we will have the right result, from the base-case.

But how can we prove the correctness of the algorithm `Algorithm`?

**EDIT**: That's what I thought when I wrote the algorithm:

We sort the array E in order to call the binary_search that will return $0$ if there are no two elements $a,b$ of $D,E$ such that $|a-b| \leq K$ or the position at which the element of $E$ is, which we subtract with an element of D and become a difference by absolute value that is less or equal to $K$. So if the binary_search returns 0, the algorithm will return N0, otherwise it will return YES.

Comment: Presumably you had in mind a reason why you wrote `Algorithm` the way you did. Also presumably the reason was something like, "Because that way it will return the correct result." If you delve into the details of that reason, it should provide some clues about how to prove the algorithm is correct. (The details of what you were thinking when you wrote this program are therefore a vital part of the question. Please provide them.)

Comment: By the way, while I think your program satisfies the literal requirements of running time, its running time has a larger constant factor than necessary. After you have sorted both arrays, the remaining code takes $O(n\lg m)$ time, whereas the remaining work could be done in $O(n+m)$ time (which is asymptotically smaller). Alternatively, sticking with your binary search procedure, what's the benefit of sorting $D$?

Comment: @DavidK You mean that it would be better not to call the binary search but to check if there are such two elements, using a for loop?

Comment: I'd probably write it as a `while` rather than a `for` since it has to look in both arrays. The idea is that once you have found that none of the first $j$ elements of $E$ is close enough to any of the first $i$ elements of $D$, you know those elements of $E$ are also too far from any of the remaining $n-i$ elements of $D$ and you don't need to check them again.

Comment: But you could get essentially the same benefit with less programming effort (now that you've already written the binary search) by just not bothering to sort $D$.

Comment: A ok... That's what I thought when I wrote the algorithm:
$$$$
We sort the array $E$ in order to call the binary_search that will return 0 if there are no two elements $a,b$ of $D,E$ such that $|a-b| \leq K$ or the position at which the element of $E$  is, which we subtract with an element of $D$ and become a difference by absolute value that is less or equal to $K$. So if the binary_search returns 0, the algorithm will return 0, otherwise it will return YES. @DavidK

Comment: @DavidK So how could we prove it correctness?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be basically on the right track already.

To prove correctness, a good first step is to prove that the algorithm will always terminate.  From the behavior of `i` and the condition of the `while` loop you can deduce that the `while` loop can only execute a finite number of times.
So as long as the binary search always terminates in finitely many steps,
the algorithm terminates.

Now show that if there are elements $a \in D$ and $b \in E$ such that $|a - b|< K$,
then sometime during the loop it will happen that `D[i]` is equal to $a$,
and when that happens your binary search will return non-zero.
(You don't have to show that the binary search will actually "find" that particular
value of $b$ in $E$, just that it can't return zero when $E$ contains such an element.)

On the other hand you also have to show that if your algorithm returns
YES then there were in fact $a \in D$ and $b \in E$ such that $|a - b|< K$.
You can do this by working backward: if it returned YES then `p` must have been
non-zero at some point in time, which means the binary search returned something
that wasn't zero, which means ... .

Whether you have to prove each of these things inductively depends on the
prescribed style of proof. In fact,
exactly how you write the proof depends a lot on the specific proof style that you're supposed to use.  In some styles the proof consists almost entirely of mathematical formulas, in others it consists mostly of text. (It looks like you're allowed
to use mostly text.)

You probably want to work out the details more carefully than the above description,
which is really just a general roadmap intended to give you confidence to proceed.

Comment: David K Could you explain me further why we  don't have to show that the binary search will actually "find" that particular value of b in E?

Comment: What I have in mind is, when we say there exists $b \in E$ that makes $|a-b|<K$ true, we would like to say we have a particular value of $b$ in mind so that we can start using that value of $b$ in our proof. But there could be several elements of $E$ that are all within the interval $(a-K,a+K)$, and it's very awkward to try to ensure in advance that our chosen $b$ is the exact same one of these that's selected as `E[mid]`. But we don't have to go to so much trouble, because the only _wrong_ search result in that case is if the search somehow returned zero.